# How to get the first decline date of an order in a chain of declines?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, amazon-redshift

I have a table `orders` with columns `id`, `date_updated`, `forwarded_to_order_id`. When an order is declined, a new order is created and the old order's `forwarded_to_order_id` column is updated to include the new order id.
I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of all orders with the date of the first ever decline for that order chain. So if order A declined on 2023-04-01, then it was forwarded to order B and order B got declined on 2023-05-01, then order C declined on 2023-06-01, I want the resulting table to be:

```
id first_decline_date
A      2023-04-01
B      2023-04-01
C      2023-04-01
```

I think I'm close, but not sure why it's not exactly working:

```
WITH RECURSIVE OrderChain (id, forwarded_to_order_id, date_updated, times_declined) AS (
SELECT
    id,
    forwarded_to_order_id,
    date_updated,
    0 AS times_declined
FROM orders
WHERE forwarded_to_order_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
    i.id,
    i.forwarded_to_order_id,
    i.date_updated,
    c.times_declined + 1 as times_declined
FROM orders i
JOIN OrderChain c
    ON i.forwarded_to_order_id = c.id
)

select * from
(
SELECT
    id AS order_id,
    MIN(date_updated) AS first_declined_date,
    MAX(times_declined) AS times_declined
FROM OrderChain
WHERE forwarded_to_order_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1
) x
where order_id in (14973, 16777, 18822, 21327, 24087, 27224, 28349);
```

the result i'm getting here is

```
id         first_decline_date       times_declined
14973   2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000      6
16777   2016-12-14 10:02:19.000000      5
18822   2017-01-14 10:02:45.000000      4
21327   2017-02-14 10:03:13.000000      3
24087   2017-03-14 10:01:21.000000      2
27224   2017-03-23 20:57:46.000000      1
```

which has the correct number of declines for each of those orders in the chain, but for some reason isn't propagating the very first decline date.

Answer (score 0):

Nm, I figured it out ... I had to make a temp table with `forwarded_from` columns. I also added another column to keep track of the declines.

```
create temp table test as
(
select
    i1.id as id,
    i1.date_updated as date_updated,
    i1.forwarded_to_order_id,
    i2.id as forwarded_from
from orders i1
left join orders i2
    on i2.forwarded_to_order_id = i1.id
);

WITH RECURSIVE OrderChain (id, forwarded_to_order_id, date_updated, decline_num) AS (
  SELECT
      id,
      forwarded_to_order_id,
      date_updated,
      0 AS decline_num
  FROM test
  WHERE forwarded_from IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      i.id,
      i.forwarded_to_order_id,
      c.date_updated,
      c.decline_num + 1 as decline_num
  FROM test i
  JOIN OrderChain c
      ON c.forwarded_to_order_id = i.id
)
select * from (
SELECT
  id AS order_id,
  date_updated,
  decline_num,
  MAX(decline_num) over(partition by date_updated) AS times_declined
FROM OrderChain
) x
where order_id in (14973, 16777, 18822, 21327, 24087, 27224, 28349)
order by order_id;
```

returns:

```
id         first_decline_date       decline_num    times_declined
14973  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       0                6
16777  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       1                6
18822  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       2                6
21327  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       3                6
24087  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       4                6
27224  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       5                6
28349  2016-11-14 10:02:01.000000       6                6
```